# SP 2007 makes IE to hang while running a jssor code

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, jssor

I'm using a [jssor slider with vertical navigation](https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider) (no-jquery version) on Sharepoint 2007 page within CEWP where i have replaced all the image links to images store under SP image library and jssor.slider.min.js file has also been uploaded under the site and link has been updated in the code.

when the page loads slider starts working but for a minute the whole Internet Explore goes for a stand still and i'm unable to click on anything and after a minute everything works normal. Surprising fact is even when IE goes for a standstill the slider loads properly and there are no console errors thrown. The same page when opened on Chrome works perfectly fine.

I tried doing everything that is mentioned on jssor site to [improve performance](http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-make-best-performance-slider.html) but no luck. I have tried using slider version with jquery but the result is same.

Please note the slider works fine when i try to open the code as non-sharepoint platform on IE.

Can some please help me in solving this.

```
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->

<!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker. -->
<!-- This demo works without jquery library. -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
<script>
    jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:1,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.5,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:4,$Cols:2,$Zoom:11,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.6,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Swing,$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:-4,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.6,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Swing,$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:4,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.5,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:0.5,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Top:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-4,y:2,$Rows:2,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Row:28},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:1,y:2,$Cols:2,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:19},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Rows: 2,
            $Cols: 6,
            $SpacingX: 14,
            $SpacingY: 12,
            $Orientation: 2,
            $Align: 156
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 960);
                refSize = Math.max(refSize, 300);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    };
</script>

<style>

    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
    /*
    .jssora05l                  (normal)
    .jssora05r                  (normal)
    .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
    */
    .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('/PublishingImages/img/a17.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
    .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
    .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
    .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

    /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
    /*
    .jssort01-99-66 .p            (normal)
    .jssort01-99-66 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
    .jssort01-99-66 .p.pav        (active)
    .jssort01-99-66 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
    */
    .jssort01-99-66 .p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 99px;
        height: 66px;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .t {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .w {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        background: url('/PublishingImages/img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
        _background: none;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .pav .c {
        top: 2px;
        _top: 0px;
        left: 2px;
        _left: 0px;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 0px solid;
        _border: #fff 2px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .p:hover .c {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 97px;
        height: 64px;
        border: #fff 1px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .p.pdn .c {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
    }

    * html .jssort01-99-66 .c, * html .jssort01-99-66 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01-99-66 .pav .c {
        /* ie quirks mode adjust */
        width /**/: 99px;
        height /**/: 66px;
    }

</style>


<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('/PublishingImages/img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 240px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/01.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-01.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/02.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-02.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/03.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-03.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/04.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-04.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/05.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-05.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/06.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-06.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/07.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-07.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/08.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-08.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/09.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-09.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/10.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-10.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/11.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-11.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/12.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-12.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/13.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-13.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="/PublishingImages/img/14.jpg" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="/PublishingImages/img/thumb-14.jpg" />
        </div>
        <a data-u="ad" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">jQuery Slider</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01-99-66" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:240px;height:480px;" data-autocenter="2">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class="w">
                    <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:248px;width:40px;height:40px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
</div>
<script>
    jssor_1_slider_init();
</script>

<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that you're using here?

Comment: i have added my code now. Thanks for showing your interest :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the jssor.slider source code has an extra branch that it goes down if it detects that the current browser mode doesn't support certain features.

```
if (!H())
     O = E(O, { $ScaleX: ["scaleX", 2], $ScaleY: ["scaleY", 2], $TranslateZ: ["translateZ", 1] });  [object]
```

It does this by checking the user agent string; any version of IE less than 11 will trigger the extra branch of code. It's likely that your SharePoint master page (or your IE compatibility view settings) are forcing the browser into IE8 mode, which is why it runs slowly on SharePoint but normally on its own.

```js
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:1,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.5,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:4,$Cols:2,$Zoom:11,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.6,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Swing,$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:-4,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.6,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$During:{$Left:[0.2,0.8],$Zoom:[0.2,0.8],$Rotate:[0.2,0.8]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Swing,$Zoom:$Jease$.$Swing,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$Swing},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.5}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:4,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.5,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1000,x:0.5,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Zoom:1,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Top:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-4,y:2,$Rows:2,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Row:28},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.7}},
          {$Duration:1200,x:1,y:2,$Cols:2,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Column:19},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$OutQuad,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.8}}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Rows: 2,
            $Cols: 6,
            $SpacingX: 14,
            $SpacingY: 12,
            $Orientation: 2,
            $Align: 156
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 960);
                refSize = Math.max(refSize, 300);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    };
jssor_1_slider_init();
```

```css
.jssora05l, .jssora05r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('/PublishingImages/img/a17.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
    .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
    .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
    .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
 .jssort01-99-66 .p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 99px;
        height: 66px;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .t {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .w {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        background: url('/PublishingImages/img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
        _background: none;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .pav .c {
        top: 2px;
        _top: 0px;
        left: 2px;
        _left: 0px;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 0px solid;
        _border: #fff 2px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .p:hover .c {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 97px;
        height: 64px;
        border: #fff 1px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01-99-66 .p.pdn .c {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 95px;
        height: 62px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
    }

    * html .jssort01-99-66 .c, * html .jssort01-99-66 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01-99-66 .pav .c {
        /* ie quirks mode adjust */
        width /**/: 99px;
        height /**/: 66px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.jssor.com/script/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
 
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('/PublishingImages/img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 240px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/df7000" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/df7000" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000000" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000000" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/00ff00" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/00ff00" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/0000ff" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/0000ff" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/555555" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/555555" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/234567" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/234567" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/449944" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/449944" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/87654321" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/87654321" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="150.00" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/12345678" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/12345678" />
        </div>
        <a data-u="ad" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">jQuery Slider</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01-99-66" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:240px;height:480px;" data-autocenter="2">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class="w">
                    <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:248px;width:40px;height:40px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
</div>
```